# 1970's Mobile home. one light dims bulbs regardless is it is new or not

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light

I pulled the fixture down and it looks like it is wired in a two wire switch loop. The two black wires are wired with a white wire.  I have not taken the actual socket apart or the wall switch. The wall switch only runs this light as far as I can tell. No matter what type or kind of bulb I put in the socket it either flickers or dims to a 1/4 or 1/2 the output or does not even light up. What would cause this and would I need to look at the wall switch wiring as well and inform you of what I see and post a picture? [image: Wiring under socket]

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the wiring very closely.  I see a nick in the insulation on the black wire hanging down to what I believe is the fixture. There are signs that the wiring has gotten hot. The switch may be worn out with carbon on the contacts and that is causing the resistance and heat. So yes check the switch. Turn the breaker off to that light. Detach the wires at the switch and wire nut them together, then turn the breaker back on.  If the light does not dim or flicker you know you need a new switch.  Speaking of breakers. if the breaker box is a Federal Pacific it has to be changed.  They are known to cause fires. It is not a matter of IF it will, it is only WHEN it will cause a fire.

Comment: thank you I will do this after I eat lunch and report back. I will also check the breaker box. I have heard that a certain type of breaker catches fire before though I did not recall what one it was. Thank you for that info as well.

Comment: Yeah, over-hot wires = somebody has been over-lamping the fixture (disrespecting the "60 watt max" sticker etc.)  Of course now in the LED age that's not a concern.